# Если есть такой ключ в json python

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api

Я пытаюсь сделать так если в json есть ключ с твоим id из вк то те будет говорить то что ты подтвердил аккаунт, а если его не будет то понятное дело что будет говорить что ты его не подтвердил.

Но почему то говорит то что я не подтвердил аккаунт, значит то что этого id нету в json файле, хоть он есть..

```
with open("testver.json", "r") as f:
    vered = json.load(f)
if f'{message.peer_id}' in vered:
    await message.answer(f"Ты уже взял подтверждение на аккаунт")
else:
    
    await message.answer(f"Теперь введи описание в Профиль пользователя  {name} чтобы подтвердить аккаунт. И потом нажми на кнопку ниже.")
    with open("testver.json", "r") as f:
        veri = json.load(f)
    veri[f'{message.peer_id}'] = {
    'name': name,
    'response': response
    }
    with open("testver.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(veri, f, indent=4)
    return f"Твоё описание для вставки в профиль: {response}"
```

Json код должен быть таким и  он должен искать message.peer_id(684720430)

```
{
    "684720430": {
        "name": "Текст",
        "response": "Hello!"
    }
```

Я не пойму что я делаю не так

Comment: А вам точно нужен peer_id а не from_id например?

Comment: теперь начало всё заменяться а не проверять

Comment: Я к тому что вы используете не тот параметр, а не к тому как ведет себя ваш код, параметр peer_id - идентификатор чата, а не пользователя

Comment: я поставил from_id, и тоже самое